# Why does webpack try to parse my readme.md files

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Webpack throws errors shown below. The build seems to work, still, what gives?

> WARNING in ./{snip}/readme.md
> Module parse failed: C:{snip}\readme.md Unexpected token (1:7)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I could not find any way to ignore files. I don't even know why it is trying to render those files.

Here are some parts of my webpack settings file:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {test: /\.hb.html$/, loader: "handlebars-loader/?helperDirs[]=" + __dirname + "/src/handlebarsHelpers"},
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader?" + JSON.stringify({
            transpileOnly: true
        })}
    ]
},
```

Entry:

```
entry: "./src/entry.ts",
```

and

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
```

I tried excluding .md files in typescript config file, also didn't work.

Comment: Is it related to the empty extension in extensions? I tried removing that, but then it won't load my entry module.

Comment: You do not have a loader for *.md files. Webpack interprets all files as JavaScript, Markdown is not JavaScript. Perhaps use the "raw-loader" for md files?

Comment: @Wazner But I don't want to load them at all.

Comment: Is there an "import 'readme.md'" file somewhere in your code?

Comment: There was a query expression as in the answer, that caused webpack to load everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem wasn't the settings, it was that my code had query expressions like these:

```
exports.getModule = function (moduleName) {
    var mod = require('./' + moduleName + '');
    return mod;
};
```

That made webpack try to load all the files, not only the ones on the entry point dependency tree.