# Errors and warnings when serving/building with a private npm package in Vue CLI

Tags: typescript, vue.js, npm, package.json, type-declaration

I have a Vue project for my company where I am importing some UI helpers that reside in a private npm package that I also created.

An example import:

```
import { UIPosition } from '@mycompany/ui-library'
```

However, when I run a build or serve command for my Vue app (with `vue-cli-service build` or `vue-cli-service serve` script), I see the following warnings in the command line:

Declaration file warning (I see a warning for every *.d.ts in my private package, but not for any other package in `node_modules`):

```
 warning  in ./node_modules/@mycompany/ui-library/library/utils/UIPosition.d.ts

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: Debug Failure. Output generation failed
    at Object.transpileModule (/myapp/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:116864:29)
    at getTranspilationEmit (/myapp/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:318:74)
    at successLoader (/myapp/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:66:15)
    at Object.loader (/myapp/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:22:12)
```

Map file warning (I see a warning only for source map files in my private package, not for any other project in `node_modules`):

```
 warning  in ./node_modules/@mycompany/ui-library/index.js.map

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> {"version":3,"file":"index.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../../src/index.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA,OAAO;AACP,OAAO,..."}
```

I also created the `@mycompany/ui-library` private package, so I have the ability to make edits. I have dug around in articles and forums and haven't found out exactly what is the ideal setup for private packages.

A few questions:

- When you import a private package, should it be picking up declaration (*.d.ts) files or map (*.js.map) files and trying to compile them, per the above warnings?
- Should I be ignoring these files as compilation inputs somehow in my project setup?
- When I create a private package, should I output source map files and declaration files? (It seems like I should be outputting them since I at least see declaration files in other popular projects in `node_modules`, which enables type inference for anyone working with the packages in their IDEs.)

Comment: Looks like for `*.d.ts` files, there is no loader associated in you main webpack config file. Are you using any loaders for these files in the main project?

Comment: When I run `vue inspect`, I see the resulting webpack config according to the Vue CLI... for ".ts" files, it is using: `node_modules/ts-loader/index.js` as a loader.

Comment: For the .map files, I'm not sure why it is trying to process these files, or if I even need to worry about processing them. Do you typically process .map files for third party packages?

Comment: I don't think you should worry about map files for 3rd party packages. Personally I do not process in my projects or never felt the need for the same. But I am not 100% sure if any issue might come because of it.

Comment: Thanks, @Sunil, I believe you're correct that you don't have to worry about map files for 3rd party projects. I ended up finding the root cause, and answering my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a simple solution for me, but admittedly hard to figure out. The problem actually had to do with a `require` statement to load images in the code of the private package.

The function below was in the private package:

```
public static get(res: string) {
    return require('@mycompany/ui-library/' + res)
}
```

Upon running `vue-cli-service build` or `vue-cli-service serve`, when Webpack sees this require statement, it apparently feels like it needs to parse/load ALL files, such as declaration files, source maps, readme, etc.

A simple solution was to change the code to explicitly list the file type in the require statement, which causes Webpack to only look for that specific file type:

```
public static getPNG(res: string) {
    return require('@mycompany/ui-library/' + res + '.png')
}
```

There are also some ways to make a more flexible require statement, using Webpack's [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#requirecontext), to be able to specify a RegEx for the types of files you'd like to load.

Also, below are some related stories I finally found that talk about Webpack trying to load README files. Although, I think my Stackoverflow question will still be relevant as I found the issue in problems loading declaration and source map files.

[Nuxt - Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853757/nuxt-module-parse-failed-unexpected-character)

[Why does webpack try to parse my readme.md files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132053/why-does-webpack-try-to-parse-my-readme-md-files)